# Running a large IN query (searching for users with an ID list) on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to detect, after a user registers, which friends from Facebook have already registered for my service. My current implementation is very CPU intensive:

```
for eachFriend in facebookFriends:
  friendUser = User.get_by_key_name(eachFriend['id'])
  if friendUser:
    friendUsers.append(friendUser)
```

I tried optimizing the query by using the IN operator:

```
 users = User.all().filter('id IN', idList).fetch(10) # the idList is the list of IDs for a users facebook friends
```

This method fails as the maximum subqueries of the IN operator is 30.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an IN operator actually makes your query less efficient: Instead of doing a fast get operation for each friend, you're doing a slow query operation (IN and != filters are broken out into multiple queries on the backend).

Instead, do a single batch fetch for all the matching suers:

```
friendUsers = User.get_by_key_name([x['id'] for x in facebookFriends])
```

This returns a list of all friends, with `None` values for any friends that don't yet exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can have each registered user store his friends in a `ListProperty` so that when I register, you can do an `=` query on that property to see who has me as a friend.  `=` queries on `ListProperties` [return all entities having the filtered-on value anywhere in the list](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ListProperty), and they don't generate subqueries the way `IN` queries do.

Just be aware of [per-entity index limits](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Big_Entities_and_Exploding_Indexes) if some of your users have tons of friends.